# What are common RSA sign exponent?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

Are there any difference between RSA encryption/decryption exponent and RSA sign/check exponent?

Comment: What do you mean by "sign/check"?  If it's any sort of authorization or digital signing, that's done with encryption and decryption.  If I encipher a message with my private key, and you decipher with my public key, you know the message was sent by somebody with my private key, presumably me.

Comment: well, yeah, but in signing you're confirming a piece of ciphertext, in encryption you create a new piece of ciphertext.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

None.  The public key of an RSA public/private pair consists of an exponent and a modulus, whether it's being used to sign or encrypt.  The most common exponent is 0x10001.

The [Wikipedia article on RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)) is pretty good.

Comment: Do you mean 0x10001 (65537) ?

Answer (score 4):

There is no structural difference between a RSA key pair used for signing and one used for encryption decryption. In theory, you could use one pair for both, but this opens up ways for new attacks, so it isn't recommended.

On the other hand, there are differences between private and public exponents:

- The public exponent can be relatively small, which shortens the key size and speeds up encryption and signature verification.
  As Charlie Martin said, 0x10001 = 2^16 + 1 = 65537 is a common choice.
- The private exponent, on the other hand, is derived from public key and the modulus' factorization, and usually in the size order of the modulus itself. As it shall stay private, it can't be small (otherwise it is easy to guess), and it also needs to fulfill the arithmetic relation to the public exponent, which makes it automatically large.

  This makes naive signing/decryption slower than the corresponding public operations, but on the other hand,
  it is possible to speed this up a bit up by using the decomposition of the modulus and the
  Chinese Remainder Theorem, i.e. calculating modulo `p` and `q` separately instead of modulo `m = p·q` and
  then combining the results.

Note that we distinguish between public (encryption/verification) and private (decryption/signing) exponents,
not between signing/verification and encryption/decryption exponents.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between an RSA key intended for signing/verification versus one intended for encryption/decryption in terms of modulus - however the value of the key usage extension in the X509 certificate will differ.

To summarise the detailed answers to [Should RSA public exponent be only in {3, 5, 17, 257 or 65537} due to security considerations?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/should-rsa-public-exponent-be-only-in-3-5-17-257-or-65537-due-to-security-c)) over at [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com):

In theory, all common implementations should allow you to use any prime > 2, but [Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Primality_of_Fermat_numbers) - numbers of the form 2^n + 1, e.g. 3, 5, 17, 257, 65537 - that are known to be prime are often favoured because they speed up calculations on one side of the operation (encrypt/decrypt, sign/verify) - and 65537 is probably the most common exponent in use at this point in time (2020/11).

However, your specific implementation may restrict the maximum value you can use in practice.